# facebook like widget for posts

Tags: facebook, widget

I use the facebook like widget a lot and I can change the url of the widget quite easily to a facebook page so when they like my website they also like the facebook page.

However is there a way to add a specific facebook post to the widget so that when they click like the like counter on the facebook post increases as well.

Is there a specific url for each post so that I can work out how to do this for posts?

Thanks,

Mat